# Replacements QGIS/Excel

Tags: qgis, expression, model, regular-expression

I have a field filled with expressions like these: 'Xm1 to Xm2'; 'Xm2 to Xm1'; 'Xm19 to Xm20'

And I also have an imported Excel table with the correspondet text to replace Xm1, Xm2, Xm(n), ..., Xm20.

It occurs that the following expression works well when among the expressions to replace I have all the possibilities from Xm1 to Xm20.

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(
"FIELD_IN_SHAPEFILE"  ,'Xm20',attribute( get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm20'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')) ,'Xm19',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm19'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm18',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm18'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm17',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm17'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm16',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm16'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm15',attribute(
get_feature('exceltable','XM','Xm15'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm14',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm14'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm13',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm13'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm12',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm12'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm11',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm11'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm10',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm10'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm9',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm9'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm8',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm8'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm7',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm7'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm6',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm6'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm5',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm5'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm4',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm4'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm3',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm3'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm2',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm2'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm1',attribute(
get_feature( 'exceltable','XM','Xm1'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE'))
```

In shapefiles where I only have combinations of Xm(n) from 1 to 9, I have to change the expressio, deteleting replacements from Xm10 to Xm20, becoming like this:

```
"FIELD_IN_SHAPEFILE"  , 'Xm9',attribute( get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm9'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm8',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm8'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm7',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm7'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm6',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm6'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm5',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm5'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm4',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm4'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm3',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm3'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm2',attribute(
get_feature(
'exceltable','XM','Xm2'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE')),'Xm1',attribute(
get_feature( 'exceltable','XM','Xm1'),'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE'))
```

I also occurs that I want this to become part of a model, not having to change all the time the number of total needed replacements. Also, the Excel table is also edited everytime I'm filling a new shapefile. I also thouthgt one table joins but i think it just works if I had something like 'Xm1' both in Excel and shapefile, but I have 'Xm1 to Xm3' so. I'm asking myself if another iteration or 'map(...' works to solve this.

P.S: In order to turn this a bit clear, examples of entries both in Attribute Table and Excel File:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is rather unclear, since we don't have your data. Please give a clear example of an entry in the attribute table, the corresponding entry in the excel file, and what should happen.

Comment: Best would be sharing sample data.

Comment: @Erik Did it. Give a look, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using regular expressions, you don't have to define a separate function for each case. You can rather look for a pattern like `'Xm' followed by one or more digits` (pseudocode) - in regex: `(Xm\\d{0,2})`.

Now create this as a variable `@var` with [`regexp_matches()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-matches), looking for a pattern with one `Xm followed by a number`, followed by `to`, followed by another `Xm followed by a number`.

This returns an array of all strings captured by capturing groups, so with `@var[0]`, you get the first element (first instance of `Xm followed by a number`). For the input string `'Xm1 to Xm2'`, `@var[0]` returns `'Xm1'`, `@var[1]` returns `'Xm2'`.

[image]

Then you can simply replace based on these variables:

```
with_variable(
    'var',
    regexp_matches(
    "FIELD_IN_SHAPEFILE" ,
    '(Xm\\d{0,2}) to (Xm\\d{0,2})'),
replace (
    replace (
        "FIELD_IN_SHAPEFILE",
        @var[0],
        attribute( 
            get_feature(
                'exceltable',
                'XM',
                @var[0]
            ),
            'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE'
        )
    ),
    @var[1],
    attribute( 
        get_feature(
            'exceltable',
            'XM',
            @var[1]
        ),
        'FIELD_IN_EXCELTABLE'
    )
))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Babel , that worked pretty well. I will have to make the same exercise with another field but with a tricky upgrade. For example, For Xm1 I have a interval of 0 - 20 and for Xm 2 I have a interval from 10 - 30, i want to code for everytime i have on XM field 'Xm1 to Xm2' it returns a interval of 0 - 30. Although the logic behind is somehow complex, like, if i have for Xm1 - 0 - 20 and for Xm2 - '>60', i want it to return only 0 - 20 or, second example, when i have for Xm1 30 - 100 and for Xm2 >80, i want it to return 30 - 100.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean. Sharing data would help. Also, showing some input and desired output would help, too. Maybe better ask a separate question on this, in the comments there is not enough space to explain.